# Shopify API for product description

Tags: php, e-commerce, shopify

I am using Shopify PHP API for updating product description. How can I include text formatting in my product description using the API? I like to be able to use formatting like bold, underline etc. for my product description. Greatly appreciate any pointers.

Answer (score 2):

You can use HTML when modifying the product’s `body_html` field and Shopify will render a formatted version when a customer looks at that product description.